# I need a synonym of 'apply' in a specific situation

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I need the right verb to decribe the situation, when one is *applying* to company (i.e. writes a letter with a request to see, whether he is meeting the criteria), but for some limited goods, not a job. It is like placing an order, but you can't make an order itself yet. You need to be approved first. (Imagine some government control - guns, drugs, etc).

The problem is, when you use *apply* + *company* it is confusing, makes you think of a job application. I want to avoid it, if possible.

I looked up in Collins, Merriam-Webster and a couple of others for synonyms, but didn't found much.

***Appeal*** sounds too formal, political or juridical.

***Make a request*** can work, but I'm not sure, if it's good in this case.

What would you recommend to do? Any good verbs out there? Or *apply* will do?

Comment: What do you mean by "meet the criteria for limited goods"?? For me, this is about **inquiring** about something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry that 'apply' in connection with a company will sound like a job application. You apply for bank loans, mortgages etc. Context should always make it clear what you mean. An 'application' well describes making a request to receive something on the basis of qualifying conditions.

In your example, where you are expressing interest in ordering something but are not yet able to order it, I think the term 'register', or 'registered interest' might be best suited.

> I have registered for the product and hope to receive one when it becomes available.

In commerce, there is the terms 'pre-order' meaning to order something before it becomes available, although this does not necessarily mean there is a limited supply. There are also 'pre-sales' which give a limited number of people access to the product before it goes on general sale. Again, this doesn't mean the product is limited, but those registering for pre-sales get priority.